# copy set of worksheets to another workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to copy some worksheets in my workbook to another workbook. I dont want any of the formulas or links to be copied from my source workbook.I need just the data. I would like to use vbscript to achieve this. Can anyone guide me to do this.

This is my attempt at making it work by doing a worksheet copy, but unfortunately it also copies the formula.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=False
Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("SourceFile.xlsx")
set objWorkbook2=objExcel.Workbooks.Add
set sheetsToCopy=objWorkbook1.Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"))
sheetsToCopy.Copy objWorkbook2.Sheets(1)
objWorkbook1.save
objWorkbook2.saveAs("TargetFile.xlsx")
objWorkbook1.close
objWorkbook2.close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=True
set objExcel=nothing
```

Comment: Please confirm you want Vbscript or VBA Code? Please note that both are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
sheetsToCopy.Copy objWorkbook2.Sheets(1)
```

with something like this:

```
i = 1
For each wks in sheetsToCopy
    If objWorkbook2.Sheets.Count < i Then objWorkbook2.Sheets.Add , objWorkbook2.WorkSheets(objWorkbook2.WorkSheets.Count)
    'adds new worksheet to end of file to keep sheet count in tact
    wks.Cells.Copy 
    With objWorkbook2.Sheets(i)
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial -4163 '--> numeric constant for PasteValues
        .Name = wks.Name
    End With
    i = i + 1
Next
```

the only issue is to make sure there are enough sheets in your new workbook. You can write a check to see how many sheets there are and if i is > then add a sheet before copying.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you Thanks!!

Comment: i m getting an error on objWorkbook2.Sheets(i).Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues that PasteSpecial method of Range class failed . I will look online and see whether i find anything

Comment: It worked great..So Range("A1") selects all data on the worksheet?? . ALso, i had named worksheets, but the new workbook did not get that name..its not a big deal, but curious if there is any syntax that i can add to make that work.

Comment: Range("A1") doesn't select data on the worksheet, it just ensures that the data gets copied from one worksheet to another in place, because the copy function will copy the upper left most cell of the copied range to the upper left most range of the range to be copied to. (long winded answer!)...  i amended the code in my answer to both check for the sheet count in new workbook and add the sheet name of the other workbook.

Comment: Ha! You beat me to it +1 for solving own problem :)